# How to implement a UI similar to "Find iPhone"

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to implement a UI for a bluetooth tracker.
There will be  `MKMapView` and a `UITableView`, just like "Find My iPhone".
[image: 1]

and when I tap on the `MKmapView`, the `tableview` will goes down with an animation, let the `MKMapView` takes the full-screen.
[image: 2]

Any suggestion to implement this kind of UI? 
Now, I am thinking a very naive way, which is to just simply change the frame size of two views. But is there any more elegant way to do it?

thank you very much.

Comment: Hiding your name but showing your location?  Okay.

Comment: Junyangs MacBook Pro eh?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some base about iOS programming, Find my iPhone UI is really simple.

Just add a map MKMapView with viewController view bounds as frame, a navigationcontroller as parent. And Custom Annotation for MKAnnotationView.

Rest, is just animation for hide navbar, or open some popup.

If you want more detail contact me.

Comment: Thank you. I used the uiview animation to change the frame of views and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figure out myself.
Add a tapGestureRecognizer to the map view.
In the callback function, change the ui frame with animation.

I thought this maybe require some fancy technique, but it didn't.